# Can lens designs be brute-force computed to create optically precise equipment?

Tags: optics, computational-physics, lenses

It seems lens design hasn't changed much over the last 50 years or so with many older manual lenses still very much being used today. Can the order, distance between and type of lens elements be brute force calculated with known values for IOR to find a design with minimal aberration and distortion?

If this is possible, is it being implemented?

Comment: What makes you believe that lens design, which is an engineering discipline, hasn't changed in half a century? It has profited from new methods just as much as any other engineering discipline. Having said that, this is not a physics question.

Comment: The lenses for optical lithography tools for semiconductor manufacturing are some of the most precise and expensive optical systems on earth. Even 20 years ago, the manufacturers were measuring the optical performance of every single lens on hand that could go in to the compound lens product, and then selecting the combinations that would provide the best performance. That optimization was pretty much brute force computation.

Answer (score 2):

Optics design has definitely changed in the past years. Lens designs for precision lenses, especially those dealing with powerful and precise lasers, are still a hot topic of development. If I understand what you mean by "brute force", then the answer is definitely yes. Check out "Zemax" software for an example of this @ www.zemax.com. A large part of the difficulty in lens design is not the theoretical design of a system, but the actual precision construction of the designed system.

Answer (score 1):

*Can the order, distance between and type of lens elements be brute force calculated with known values for IOR to find a design with minimal aberration and distortion?*

Sure. Actually the nicest implementations for me are the so called *adaptive* optics, like the [spatial light modulator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spatial_light_modulator) and the [deformable mirrors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deformable_mirror).

The principle is to have several physical microscopic objects which can change the phase profile locally on a wavefront. These "pixels" can be tiny mirrors mounted on piezo actuators in a grid, or a deformable reflective membrane which is pushed and deformed by a similar grid of actuators, or pixels filled with liquid crystals which change index as a function of applied voltage.

The brute force is used this way: 1) you create an image using, among other optics, the adaptive element. 2) aberrations need to be quantified in the image 3) a [PID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PID_controller) algorithm changes the pattern of positions for the small actuators (or pixel voltage for liquid crystals) to optimize the image minimizing the aberrations.
The final pattern which optimizes the image depends on everything on the optical path and it's found after several iterations.